# Python: Camelot-PY (Error: GhostscriptNotFound while it is installed) for M1 MacOS

Tags: apple-m1, python-camelot

Problems using Camelot-py for PDF parsing. Cannot locate 'gs' package, although it has been installed in any imaginable way... Using M1 Monterey OS.

While GS is clearly installed (gs launches from Terminal root just fine), home-brew installation of python / Xcode, PATH variables added through 'export PATH'. Still getting the same error with Ghostscript not being installed when trying to parse a PDF table.

Any suggestions / experience on this please? One would have thought it should not be such a massive pain to resolve...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, which was resolved by installing camelot-py from Anaconda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge camelot-py
```